# Non-relational field given in select_related: ' '. Choices are: (none)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-select-related

I have two models from different apps:

```
class Measure(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default="2018-01-23 15:55")
    average = models.FloatField(default=0)

class Sensor(models.Model):
    measure=models.ForeignKey(Measure, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value= models.FloatField(default=0)
```

I'm calling all data coming from sensors as follow:

```
new_context = Sensor.objects.select_related('measure__date')
```

However, I receive this error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Non-relational field given in
>   select_related: 'date'. Choices are: (none)

from documentation, I should be using select_related instead of prefetch_related, and the call seems to be coherent.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just do `Sensor.objects.select_related('measure')`. After that you may get the attributes from the queryset.

Comment: Similar issues can arise when upgrading old Django code. This type of error would silently fail before Django 1.10 (or 1.8 for non-nested). See release notes for [1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/1.10/#select-related-prohibits-non-relational-fields-for-nested-relations) and [1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/1.8/#select-related-now-checks-given-fields).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `select_related` only fields that are `ForeignKey` should be set. In your case the issue it that `date` field is a `DateTimeField` and not `ForeignKey`.

So in order to solve it just do it:

```
new_context = Sensor.objects.select_related('measure')
```

You can see examples of using syntax in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

Comment: thanks! By doing this if I call `print (new_context[0])` i get  `Sensor object (688)`. However, if I do `print (new_context[0].date)` then I get the error **AttributeError: 'Sensor' object has no attribute 'date'**. How is that possible?

Comment: @Alvaro `].measure.date`